# jQuery how to make a .get() query when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

So im trying to build a one page website.Think of it has a customer support portal.I want to run a .get() when a button is clicked without refreshing or redirecting.
Here is the html:

```
 <div class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active" id="Raiseticketbtn">Raise a new ticket</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" id="Viewticketsbtn">View tickets</li>
  </div>
```

Here is the jQuery side of things:

```
   $("#Viewticketsbtn").on("click",function(){
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(".supportform").hide("slow");
  $.get("/support",function(data){

  })
})
```

Here is the express side of things:

```
  app.get("/support",function(req,res){
    Support.find({},function(err,allsupport){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.json(allsupport);
        }
    })
})
```

How do i make a .get() req to the server without refresshing the page.I figured out i have to use AJAX.Is it possible to make a .get() to the server when the "Viewticketsbtn" is clicked?
Idea is to retrive all the tickets raised by a single person using AJAX but im not sure how to call a .get() when the "Viewticketbtn" is clicked.Please hep me out.

Comment: "Is it possible"...yes. the code you've written should be doing it already. Specifically what problem are you having with that code? Have you tried to debug it? It's unclear what you need help with exactly. Are you unsure how to deal with the response, perhaps?

Comment: Your code is already doing what you require, making that AJAX call when the button is clciked. All you need to do is handle the response in the callback function. The `data` argument will hold the values the server returns to you.

Comment: $.get("/support" should load data without cause refresh, but it may happen that refresh can caused by button "click" event. i suggest you to add ```$("#Viewticketsbtn").on("click",function(e){  e.preventDefault()```

Comment: Actually i had a "debugger" in place like so   ` $.get("/support",function(data){
       debugger
  })`  So that when i click the viewticketsbtn chrome developer tools would help me to stop the code and i can review the data coming back.But that didnt work out as i expected @ADyson

Comment: Ok. So what happened instead? It's not much use to tell us what _didn't_ happen, if you don't also describe what _did_ happen. Did the "click" event occur correctly and run the rest of the code to add and remove classes? Did you also check the Network tool to see what happened to the request? Or the Console? Please give us a precise description of the behaviour, rather than just saying "it didn't work out" - that doesn't give us any real clues.

Comment: ya the click listener  did run the rest of the code properly.The debugger inside the .get() didnt work.

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with `$.get("/support",` and the *rest of the code/question is not relevant* - all the parts about button clicking / add/removing classes you've confirm worked, so they have no place in the question and should be removed for clarity.  Have a read of [mcve] with the emphasis on *minimal*.

Comment: _"The debugger inside the .get() didnt work"_ ... ok so, again I will explain: "didn't work" is not a useful clue by itself. What **did** happen? Did you get an error in the console instead? Did the request show up in the Network tool? If so, what response code did you get from the server? These are the important pieces of information when debugging an AJAX request.